# Using usemap in div without img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am displaying my images using div tag and background-image property of css class. Now I want to use the image as map. How can I use the usemap attribute inside the div without the img tag? Note that I want to avoid the img tag.

Here's my css

```
.myStyle
{
  background-image: url('../images/myimg.png');
}
```

Here's the div

```
<div class=myStyle></div>
```

Comment: you can refer this tutorial : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_object_usemap.asp

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use usemap but you can mimic the usemap with css using a tag inside the div and postion them based on your links, refer this http://jsfiddle.net/yAZxK/35/

HTML

```
<div class=myStyle>
<a id="link1" href="#">Link</a>
<a id="link2" href="#">Link</a>
<a id="link3" href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a#link1, a#link2, a#link3 {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;   
    background: transparent;
    text-indent: -9999px; 
}
#link1 {
    left: 10px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 84px;

}
#link2 {
    left: 55px;
    top: 45px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 39px;    
}
#link3 {
    top: 45px;
    left: 124px;
     width: 130px;
     height: 39px;    
}
```